# How to execute unit tests in random order in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

I would like to execute unit tests in a random order inside visual studio. Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: Put on a blindfold and click randomly with the mouse.

Comment: It's considered bad practice for your unit tests to have ordering dependencies. You shouldn't care about the order in which they are executed.

Comment: @SoMoS: what language are you using and what test framework are you using

Comment: This is a valid question. For example, Google Test has a `--gtest_shuffle` flag. The reason you do this is to ensure that you are not accidentally relying on a dependency between tests.

Comment: @Marcelo: as far as I know its a standard way of working to ensure that your UTs aren't needing something created by another UTs

Comment: @Adamski: I have over 500 UT ... I don't feel like doing this each day :)

Comment: @Lie: The UT are in C++ and in C# and I'm using only the UT tools available at VS2008 and executing them inside VS2008.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks, that's an aspect I had never considered (I do try write my unit tests independently, but had never thought to test that they actually are).

Answer (score 2):

Is far as I can see, they are always executed in a sort of random order. You can see the actual order in the trx file. I can't say how "reliably random" it is.

Comment: They look random at he first sight but If you run them several times they always run in the same random order unless you insert new test so it's not random at all :(

Answer (score -2):

Unit tests should be self contained and not impact on any other tests and all unit tests should be run to ensure the changes you made have not broken something. There is no point in running them randomly.

Each test in all the testing frameworks I know are run as a separate unit and therefore dependencies cannot occur between tests. Even items you setup in Setup methods are recreated for each unit test.

Therefore there is no point in running your tests randomly as they are self contained.

If you are talking about integration tests then that is another story.

Comment: As I mentioned above, running tests in a random order is a time-tested practice to ensure that you do not accidentally have dependencies between tests. Many test frameworks do this automatically.

Comment: Agree with Nate. If you run your UT always in the same order maybe they work just because that special order, its better to shuffle them.

Comment: If you do unit test of something that persist in some way you could end with dependences between them. Anyway you're right, I was talking about IntegrationTests rather than UnitTest but that does not change the topic IMHO.

Comment: Unit Tests vs Integration Tests are very very different and cannot be viewed as the same. Unit Tests by their definition test one unit of code, there is no dependency and no persistance.

Comment: @skyfoot -1. You aren't actually addressing his question. Whether he should or should **not** run them in a different order is another story

Comment: @dtmland in his comment on his question he mentions that running them randomly prevents unit tests conflicting with each other and that's why he wants to run them randomly. I am pointing out that unit tests run in isolation and don't impact each other.